# WMS and Google maps in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, google

I use QGIS and I have a problem with WMS file. Since WMS maps are not overlapped to Google Maps, so to solve this issue I create a new shape file drawing the image from WMS maps but when I save this file with Google Maps frame of reference (EPSG 4236), my image is pointed in a unknown point in Africa.

---

So I enough to change frame of reference... Do I have to use projection on the fly?

Yes, I am using 2.14.22 I tryied the version 3 but is quite different and I have difficult to find many features... For example projection on the fly is configured in a different manner

Comment: Google Maps *doesn't* use EPSG 4326.  It uses Web Mercator (3857).  The point is more likely to be *off the west coast of Africa* at the origin of Prime Meridian and Equator (Null Island).

Comment: It sounds like you are using version 2 of QGIS. you will find things are much easier with version 3

Comment: Yes I have the version 2